# C++ Builder, TShapes, How to change color OnMouseEnter

Tags: c++, c++builder, onmouseover, c++builder-xe7

Hej! I'm trying to programmatically create a TShape. When I run the program and click the button - everything works. But when I click the button again, the event OnMouseEnter(OnMouseLeave) works only with the LAST Shape. Does not work with any of the previous.

```
    int i=0;
    TShape* Shape[50];
    void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    int aHeight = rand() % 101 + 90;
    int bWidth = rand() % 101 + 50;
    i++;
    Shape[i] = new TShape(Form1);
    Shape[i]->Parent = this;
    Shape[i]->Visible = true;
    Shape[i]->Brush->Style=stCircle;
    Shape[i]->Brush->Color=clBlack;

    Shape[i]->Top =    aHeight;
    Shape[i]->Left = bWidth;
    Shape[i]->Height=aHeight;
    Shape[i]->Width=bWidth;

    Shape[i]->OnMouseEnter = MouseEnter;
    Shape[i]->OnMouseLeave = MouseLeave;

    Label2->Caption=i;


    void __fastcall TForm1::MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    Shape[i]->Pen->Color = clBlue;
     Shape[i]->Brush->Style=stSquare;
     Shape[i]->Brush->Color=clRed;
}



void __fastcall TForm1::MouseLeave(TObject *Sender)
{
    Shape[i]->Pen->Color = clBlack;
    Shape[i]->Brush->Style=stCircle;
    Shape[i]->Brush->Color=clBlack;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `OnMouse...` event handlers are using `i` to index into the `Shape[]` array, but `i` contains the index of the *last* `TShape`  you created (and BTW, you are not populating `Shape[0]`m as you are incrementing `i` before creating the first `TShape`).

To do what you are attempting, the event handlers need to use their `Sender` parameter to know which `TShape` is *currently* triggering each event, eg:

```
TShape* Shape[50];
int i = 0;

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
    ...

    Shape[i] = new TShape(this);
    Shape[i]->Parent = this;
    ...
    Shape[i]->OnMouseEnter = MouseEnter;
    Shape[i]->OnMouseLeave = MouseLeave;

    ++i;
    Label2->Caption = i;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MouseEnter(TObject *Sender)
{
    TShape *pShape = static_cast<TShape*>(Sender);

    pShape->Pen->Color = clBlue;
    pShape->Brush->Style = stSquare;
    pShape->Brush->Color = clRed;
}

void __fastcall TForm1::MouseLeave(TObject *Sender)
{
    TShape *pShape = static_cast<TShape*>(Sender);

    pShape->Pen->Color = clBlack;
    pShape->Brush->Style = stCircle;
    pShape->Brush->Color = clBlack;
}
```